# How to retain rendering data of a texture view when it called detachFromWindow()?

Tags: android, textureview

I want to add a textureview into a viewgroup, and this viewgroup will call attachToWindow and detachFromWindow frequently. In order not to show a black view, I saved the surfacetexture of this textureview like this.

It's useful for most mobile phones, but it's useless for some devices with GPU Mali-T624~860/Intel HD Graphics for Atom x5. And the GlEs version of these useless devices is under 3.2 (3.1/3.0).

How can I solve the problem?

```
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
            initPlayer();
        }
        if (mSurfaceTexture == null) {
            mSurfaceTexture = surface;
            if (mSurface == null) {
                mSurface = new Surface(mSurfaceTexture);
                mMediaPlayer.setSurface(mSurface);
            }
        } else {
            mVideoTextureView.setSurfaceTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
        }
    }
```

I find some log when the method doesn't work.

queueBuffer: slot 1 is dropped, handle=0xaf850780

Comment: I find some log when the method doesn't work.

Comment: Why not create a bitmap of the view and save it?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with a very simple custom TextureView.

Create a new subclass of TextureView and override the method of "destroyHardwareResources". Remember to make this method empty.
Then you will get what you want.

```
public class MyTextureView extends TextureView {
...
...
@Override
protected void destroyHardwareResources() {

}
...
...
```

}